# Computing covariance matrix using numpy and generators

Tags: python, numpy, generator

Numpy has the function to compute covariance from an array which is fine. However, I would like to do it using generators to save memory. Is there some way to do this without writing my own cov-function?

Comment: We might need a little more information about the size of your array etc, to highlight exactly how/why you want to use generators

Comment: Well, the question was more of academic character in first instance. I understand that the construction might not be the right way to go in many cases, but that was what I wanted to discuss.

Comment: If you look into the source of `cov` (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1780), everything passed in will be copied and converted to an `np.array` anyway. So you don't save any memory by passing generators to `cov`. If you really want generators I think you're stuck with writing you own function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following implementation:

```
from numpy import outer

def gen_cov(g):
    mean, covariance = 0, 0
    for i, x in enumerate(g):
       diff = x - mean
       mean += diff/(i+1)
       covariance += outer(diff, diff) * i / (i+1)
    return covariance/i
```

You may want to use something different from `numpy.outer` depending on what the generator elements are. This is a Python implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324464/4080129).