# Running (one pass) calculation of covariance

Tags: c#, statistics, covariance

I got a set of 3d vectors (x,y,z), and I want to calculate the covariance matrix without storing the vectors.

I will do it in C#, but eventually I will implement it in C on a microcontroller, so I need the algorithm in itself, and not a library.

Pseudocode would be great also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. It is based on this article about  [how to calculate covariance manually](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Covariance) and this one about [calculating running variance](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/). And then I adapted the algorithm in the latter to calculate covariance instead of variance, given my understanding of it from the first article.

```
public class CovarianceMatrix
{
    private int _n;
    private Vector _oldMean, _newMean,
                    _oldVarianceSum, _newVarianceSum,
                    _oldCovarianceSum, _newCovarianceSum;

    public void Push(Vector x)
    {
        _n++;
        if (_n == 1)
        {
            _oldMean = _newMean = x;
            _oldVarianceSum = new Vector(0, 0, 0);
            _oldCovarianceSum = new Vector(0, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            //_newM = _oldM + (x - _oldM) / _n;
            _newMean = new Vector(
                _oldMean.X + (x.X - _oldMean.X) / _n,
                _oldMean.Y + (x.Y - _oldMean.Y) / _n,
                _oldMean.Z + (x.Z - _oldMean.Z) / _n);

            //_newS = _oldS + (x - _oldM) * (x - _newM);
            _newVarianceSum = new Vector(
                _oldVarianceSum.X + (x.X - _oldMean.X) * (x.X - _newMean.X),
                _oldVarianceSum.Y + (x.Y - _oldMean.Y) * (x.Y - _newMean.Y),
                _oldVarianceSum.Z + (x.Z - _oldMean.Z) * (x.Z - _newMean.Z));

            /* .X is X vs Y
             * .Y is Y vs Z
             * .Z is Z vs X
             */
            _newCovarianceSum = new Vector(
                _oldCovarianceSum.X + (x.X - _oldMean.X) * (x.Y - _newMean.Y),
                _oldCovarianceSum.Y + (x.Y - _oldMean.Y) * (x.Z - _newMean.Z),
                _oldCovarianceSum.Z + (x.Z - _oldMean.Z) * (x.X - _newMean.X));

            // set up for next iteration
            _oldMean = _newMean;
            _oldVarianceSum = _newVarianceSum;
        }
    }
    public int NumDataValues()
    {
        return _n;
    }

    public Vector Mean()
    {
        return (_n > 0) ? _newMean : new Vector(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public Vector Variance()
    {
        return _n <= 1 ? new Vector(0, 0, 0) : _newVarianceSum.DivideBy(_n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works out! If you want to move your window and remove the values leaving the current window you simply subtract from the old covariance sum, e.g. for x you first compute the "oldMean" as tempMean.X = ((oldMean.x * n) - x) / (n-1) and then update the covariance sum with oldCov.x -= (y - oldMean.y) * (x - tempMean.x)
and then update your oldMean to tempMean.

Comment: For completeness, you'll need a public method to actually return the Covariance that has been calculated.

Answer (score 8):

The formula is simple if you have `Matrix` and `Vector` classes at hand:

```cpp
Vector mean;
Matrix covariance;
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
  Vector diff = points[i] - mean;
  mean += diff / (i + 1);
  covariance += diff * diff.transpose() * i / (i + 1);
}
covariance *= 1 / points.size()
```

I personally always prefer this style rather than the two-pass calculation. The code is short and the results are flawless.

`Matrix` and `Vector` can have fixed dimension and can be easily coded for this purpose. You can even rewrite the code into discrete floating-point calculations and avoid computing the symmetric part of the covariance matrix.

Note that there is a vector *outer product* on the second last row of code. Not all vector libraries interpret it correctly.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up variance of sum of random variables and sample variance. The former increases linearly, but the latter converges to population variance, as the number of points increases. The question is most likely about population covariance matrix, but your code produces covariance that increases linearly, so you should divide the result by number of points to get the correct result.

Comment: Let's consider 1D case: 1x1 covariance matrix is just variance. If there are 5 points (1,1,1,2,2), then population variance is 0.24, but your code produces 1.2

Comment: Variance is this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html. Whoever wants to calculate the estimated value of variance can multiply the result by n / (n - 1).

Comment: I'm not talking about difference between biased and unbiased sample variance, but rather missing division by number of points. I calculated variance of points (1,1,1,2,2) again using link to Wolfram that you provided and got ((1-1.4)^2*3+(2-1.4)^2*2)/5=0.24, but your code returns totally different result 1.2. You can't get the expected result by multiplying by n / (n - 1).

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'll correct the formula. Do you know exactly how it should look?

Comment: You can divide covariance by points.size() after the loop: `covariance = covariance/points.size()`. It is also possible to divide it inside the loop, but I prefer to move divisions outside whenever possible.

Comment: Also note that `1 / points.size()` results in zero because of integer division. It is better to replace it by `1.0 / points.size()` to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The code from emu is elegant, but requires an additional step to be correct:

```
Vector mean;
Matrix covariance;
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
  Vector diff = points[i] - mean;
  mean += diff / (i + 1);
  covariance += diff * diff.transpose() * i / (i + 1);
}

covariance = covariance/(points.size()-1);
```

Note the final step of normalizing the covariance.

Comment: The covariance matrix in my formula is correctly normalized for an exact data set. What you mean is _sample covariance_, a statistical estimate from a limited number of measurements. And then, your last line should read `covariance = covariance * (points.size() / (points.size() - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example in R to demonstrate the principle:

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(22), ncol = 2)
a1 <- a[1:10, ]
a2 <- a[2:11, ]
cov(a1)
cov(a2)
m <- 10

# initial step
m1.1 <- mean(a1[, 1]) 
m1.2 <- mean(a1[, 2]) 

c1.11 <- cov(a1)[1, 1]
c1.22 <- cov(a1)[2, 2]
c1.12 <- cov(a1)[1, 2]


#step 1->2
m2.1 <- m1.1 + (a[11, 1] - a[1, 1])/m
m2.2 <- m1.2 + (a[11, 2] - a[1, 2])/m

c2.11 <- c1.11 + (a[11, 1]^2 - a[1, 1]^2)/(m - 1) + (m1.1^2 - m2.1^2) * m/(m - 1)
c2.22 <- c1.22 + (a[11, 2]^2 - a[1, 2]^2)/(m - 1) + (m1.2^2 - m2.2^2) * m/(m - 1)
c2.12 <- c1.12 + (a[11, 1] * a[11, 2] - a[1, 1]*a[1, 2])/(m - 1) + 
   (m1.1 * m1.2 - m2.1 * m2.2) * m/(m - 1)

cov(a2) - matrix(c(c2.11, c2.12, c2.12, c2.22), ncol=2)
```